# Django RemoteUserBackend

Tags: django, custom-authentication, remoteusermiddleware

I'm trying to use multiple Authentication backends in Django 1.5.

I want to use `RemoteUserBackend` with a custom `header` and the standard `ModelBackend`

Seems like I can make one or the other work, but not both. If I try to log in using `ModelBackend` i get this error:

```
"'CustomHeaderMiddleware' object has no attribute 'authenticate'"
```

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'myapp.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware',
    ...
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'myapp.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware',
)
```

custom_auth.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import RemoteUserMiddleware

class CustomHeaderMiddleware(RemoteUserMiddleware):
    header = "CUSTOM_USERID"
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. It works if I set the 'CUSTOM_USERID', but I can't use the standard login.

What am I missing?

Comment: why is a middleware in authentication backends ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'myapp.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware'` from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Also make sure `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`, is before `'myapp.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Example:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myapp.backends.custom_auth.CustomHeaderMiddleware',
    ...
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```